# Magento 2 How to charge extra fee

Tags: magento2, create-order, extrafee

I create order **programmatically** and   i want to charge extra  fee  during the order, please don't offer extensions. I use the code bellow for the created order and i need charge extra fee in that code , I tried to change the grand total before placing the order, 
**but this doesn't help me, thanks**

```
<?php
    namespace YourNameSpace\ModuleName\Helper;

    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
         /**
        * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
        * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
        * @param Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey $formkey,
        * @param Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        * @param Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        * @param Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
        */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService  
        ) {
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_product = $product;
            $this->_formkey = $formkey;
            $this->quote = $quote;
            $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
            $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
            $this->orderService = $orderService;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        /**
         * Create Order On Your Store
         * 
         * @param array $orderData
         * @return array
         * 
        */
        public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
            $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
            $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
            263135
            if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
                //If not avilable then create this customer 
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                        ->setStore($store)
                        ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                        ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                        ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                        ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
                $customer->save();
            }
            $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
            $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
            // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
            $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
            $quote->setCurrency();
            $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

            //add items in quote
            foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
                $product=$this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
                $product->setPrice($item['price']);
                $quote->addProduct(
                    $product,
                    intval($item['qty'])
                );
            }

            //Set Address to quote
            $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

            // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

            $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                            ->collectShippingRates()
                            ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
            $quote->setPaymentMethod('moneris'); //payment method
            $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
            $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

            // Set Sales Order Payment
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'moneris']);

            // Collect Totals & Save Quote
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();

            // Create Order From Quote
            $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

            $order->setEmailSent(0);
            $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
            if($order->getEntityId()){
                $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
            }else{
                $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to display it in the checkout and cart or just before the order placed ?

Comment: Vinz, only before the order , thanks

Comment: Robinio Found any solution.